# How to write the documentation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my code in my controller.js file

```
       /**
         * This is my description
         * @param {object} param - aaaaaaaaaa
         */
        $scope.getSelectedClassParam = function(param) {
            ...             
            return "true";
        };
```

I work in eclipse btw.

The code, like it is now...does the following

I place the cursor above the getSelectedClassParam
then a yellow rectangle pops up and shows the description of the class...the description looks like this:

[image]

But i need it to be SOMETHING like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript have a standard for commenting functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126310/does-javascript-have-a-standard-for-commenting-functions)

Comment: not a duplicate, it just does not work...btw i got a code from there as well

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but maybe try to use the auto-formatter in Eclipse?
Auto format in Eclipse: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>


[Eclipse - Key bindings](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your functions like this:

```
function foo(bar){
   return bar;
};
```

Thing is that Eclipse generates documentation for declarations! An assignment expression you use to declare a function is no different than an expression like `x=1;` and Eclipse does not generate documentation for expressions.

I would recommend checking out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname). It explains the differences in function declarations.

Comment: I did that as well, for the first time, it does seem legit, but, once i go over the function...its again the same....the difference is only that the editor recognizes the parameters, and adds the @param part himself....but in the yellow rectangle, there is still the same problem...

Answer (score -1):

This is a duplicate of:

[Does JavaScript have a standard for commenting functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126310/does-javascript-have-a-standard-for-commenting-functions)

I think the closest to a standard, would be JSDoc.  http://usejsdoc.org